# Html Agility Pack/C#: how to create/replace tags?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

The task is simple, but I couldn't find the answer.

Removing tags (nodes) is easy with Node.Remove()... But how to replace them?

There's a ReplaceChild() method, but it requires to create a new tag. How do I set the contents of a tag? InnerHtml and OuterHtml are read only properties.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See this code snippet:

```
public string ReplaceTextBoxByLabel(string htmlContent) 
{
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

  foreach(HtmlNode tb in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@type='text']"))
  {
    string value = tb.Attributes.Contains("value") ? tb.Attributes["value"].Value : "&nbsp;";
    HtmlNode lbl = doc.CreateElement("span");
    lbl.InnerHtml = value;

    tb.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(lbl, tb);
  }

  return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: it's fine but can throw error if input doesn't exists on dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure InnerHtml is a read only property?

The HTMLAgility pack's documentation says otherwise: (Cut & Paste)

```
Gets or Sets the HTML between the start and end tags of the object.

Namespace:  HtmlAgilityPack
Assembly:  HtmlAgilityPack (in HtmlAgilityPack.dll) Version: 1.4.0.0 (1.4.0.0)
Syntax
C# 
public virtual string InnerHtml { get; set; }
```

If it is read only could you post some code?