# Regex replace a pattern with another pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone help me write a regex have below result to replace bbcode with html tag, for here i want to replace `[b][/b]` with `<strong></strong>`

So this:

```
 "fsdfs [b]abc[/b] dddfs [b]abc[/b] fdsfdsfs [b]abcfsdfs"
```

Becomes:

```
 "fsdfs <strong>abc</strong> dddfs <strong>abc</strong> fdsfdsfs [b]abcfsdfs"
```

Would the following Regex help to solve this problem?

```
 string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]", @"\<stront\>(.*?)\<\/strong\>");
```

Comment: `<stront\>` should probably be `<strong\>` what ever you try to do.

Comment: I understood it, the question was essentially: how can I convert `"fsdfs [b]abc[/b] dddfs [b]abc[/b] fdsfdsfs [b]abcfsdfs"` to `"fsdfs <strong>abc</strong> dddfs <strong>abc</strong> fdsfdsfs [b]abcfsdfs"` with regex.  Putting both the input and output on the same line was an unfortunate choice.

Comment: I'm guessing that you only want to replace [B] with [STRONG] where the [B] has a closing [/B] in the original string. This is not a good thing to do in Regex, because regex is not good for parsing HTML. Why? Read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1758162

Comment: Why are you escaping the angle brackets in the replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work:

```
string s = "fsdfs [b]abc[/b] dddfs [b]abc[/b] fdsfdsfs [b]abcfsdfs";
string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]", @"<strong>$1</strong>");
```

Example: http://ideone.com/xwP1EL

Comment: As a thought experiment, this works very well. In practice though, it's not a good way to manage Html at all; It can't hurt to consider using something like the Html Agility pack instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540154/html-agility-pack-c-how-to-create-replace-tags